# Asking name and storing it?

Tags: java, android, string

I have huge problem. Have searching answer from many places but I do not find answer to question.

I have 2 classes in java. One is "main" and other is "menu"

On main, there is editText where person can type name and button ok.

When you press ok, I want to specific thing happen. That is where I need help. I am newcomer in Android.

I want that in other class, where will be main application and stuff, the entered name would be displayed. For example "Welcome " + name

I have tried many ways but I do not get it to work. So I want it to get one of 2 possible ways.

1. Set string in class 1 and then when it goes class 2, then it imports the string from class 1 to class 2 so I can use it.
2. I set string in class 2 and then in Class 1 I change the string in class 2, so the main 'data' string is actually in class 2, where I will continue using it if needed!

I have searched it from many places, used google and this database, but haven't found answer.

My codes are really nothing much, so no point pasting them here :).

Thanks for the help!

---

edit:// Ok, here are some codes then :)

```
package viimane.voimalus.incule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ViimaneVoimalusActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button oknupp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nimiOK);
        oknupp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.in" +cule.REALMENU"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
package viimane.voimalus.incule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RealMenu extends Activity {

    EditText nimesisestus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.peamenu);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Elven! I know that you might not think your code amounts to much, but it allows us to tailor our answers to your situation.  If you do add your code you are much more likely to get an answer to your question!

Comment: @James Ok, I added them :). I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show any code at all, so the answer won't be too detailed.

1. You can pass a String in the intent used to start the second activity, using [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. In the second activity you may get the string by calling [getStringExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29). If you don't know much about starting activity and intents, there are many resources on the web, for example - [this one](http://www.droidnova.com/use-intents-to-start-other-activities,76.html).
2. To receive text input use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and to put text on the screen (that the user can't cange) use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Those are starting points. Next time I hope the question will be more focused.

Comment: Well try and use the information I gave you, if you have problems, ask  in Stackoverflow, but I am not going to write it from scratch yet...

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string as parameter to the constructor of the menu class like this:

menu m = new menu(mystring);

then in the constructor save the atribute to your class

private String mystring;

`menu(String mystring)
{
    this.mystring = mystring;
}`

Comment: He's talking about android. it should be passed through intent.